# How to schedule notifications in android and send at fixed time

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification, notifications

We have an android and iOS application to which we send around 10 different types of notifications in a day. Currently we are using an architecture in which we run a cron to schedule the notification at some time time and after that we run a separate cron for sending message. The problem being faced is that as the users have increased the scheduling and sending processes take several hours which doesn't allow us to send the notifications at the desired time. We are using php and MySQL.

Is their some other architecture or technology which would reduce the time being taken for this activity?
[Edit]
This question is concerned more abut the back end architecture that can be used in house depending upon third party unlike that in [Is GCM service reliable for large scale push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068912/is-gcm-service-reliable-for-large-scale-push-notification)

Comment: maybe check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068912/is-gcm-service-reliable-for-large-scale-push-notification

Comment: Thanks for the link. We are already using GCM and APNS and all the mentioned suggestions provided by SCCL. Would like some insight on the backend architecture and enhance the in house system.

Comment: the easiest most straight forward is to break it down, having multiple threads and later machines send the notifications of a segment of your phones, this of course means that your back end can keep up. If your backend doesn't then you need to up your mysql game, or if it exceeds a certain scale get a NoSQL solution all together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is GCM service reliable for large scale push notification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068912/is-gcm-service-reliable-for-large-scale-push-notification)

Answer (score 0):

By using `BroadCastReceiver` you can schedule time and send notification on the particular time you given in the Receiver.